# Debugging on Moto 360

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wear-os

I am trying to get debugging over Bluetooth working on my Moto 360. I am following these [instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) but when I put in `adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444` all that happens is adb runs through its list of available commands again.

In the wear companion app `Debugging over Bluetooth` is enabled, Host says Disconnected and Target says connected.

On the watch itself ADB debugging is enabled and Debug over Bluetooth is enabled

I also references this [article](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2014/07/16/common-android-wear-tasks-for-developers/) which has a little more information but still nothing

adb see's my phone just never the watch

What am I missing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured it out, instead of doing `adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444` all at once I broke it up into 2 seperate commands

first command

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
```

second command

```
adb connect localhost:4444
```

then the watch asked me to authorize with the computer.

I have never been good with command prompt stuff so I dont know if that was just a noob mistake or what but just in-case anyone else runs into the same problem

Comment: this step: then the watch don't asked me to authorize with the computer.

Comment: When Offline issues happen, try this.. http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/10/android-moto360.html

Comment: this is somewhat outdated, but I thought I add my learning. It doesn't work when concatenated with `;` but it did when concatenated with `&&`. So I created an alias `alias moto="adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub && adb connect localhost:4444"` which works well for me. For the difference in `;` and `&&` see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47758/11989)

Comment: Nice solution! Sometimes, the first command complains that it can't connect to the device. This might be because you have Android emulators running, or multiple devices connected. The easiest solution for this is to shutdown the emulator(s) and disconnect all the other ADB-enabled Android devices.

Answer (score 12):

I had an issue with the accepted answer where upon trying to connect it would return:

"unable to connect to localhost:4444: cannot connect to localhost:4444: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)"

In this case the solution for me was:

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Comment: `adb connect localhost:4444` did not work so tried this with ip address and worked on my Motorola 360

Answer (score 8):

Enable `Debugging over Bluetooth` in `Android Wear` application on smartphone solved my issue. Thanks for the reference to this [article](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2014/07/16/common-android-wear-tasks-for-developers/)

[image: Enable <code>Debugging over Bluetooth</code> in <code>Android Wear</code> application]

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset to factory defaults on my wearable and perform these [steps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) again to get it to work. I was switching between two computers.